# Simplest way to return an array that is nested in multiple arrays

Tags: python

I have a situation where I have data that sometimes can be nested in multiple array layers.

Some times the data can be nested like:

```
[ [ 'green', 'blue', 'red' ] ]
```

Other times

```
[[[ ['green', 'blue', 'red' ] ]]]
```

I want to extract the array and return it, what would be the most pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Are there any other elements in the parent lists? or are you simply looking to strip the excess nesting?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Stripping the "nesting" is easy - but I'd look more to not having it in the first place ie, if unpredictable results - then there's a flaw somewhere that needs addressing...

Comment: @JonClements I agree with you on your approach of not having bad data in the first place but for the time being I need to strip the nesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy is your best friend as always :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[[ ['green', 'blue', 'red' ] ]]]
>>> print np.squeeze(a)
['green' 'blue' 'red']
```

The numpy function `squeeze()` remove all the dimensions that are 1 in your array.

Comment: Don't agree with `your best friend as always` - but +1

Comment: :) why? Numpy has ever let you down in the past?

Answer (score 3):

```
def get_nested_list(a):
    if len(a) == 1 and isinstance(a[0], list):
        return get_nested_list(a[0])
    return a
```

Examples:

```
>>> get_nested_list([[[ ['green', 'blue', 'red' ] ]]])
['green', 'blue', 'red']
>>> get_nested_list([[[[1, 2],[3]]]])
[[1, 2], [3]]
```

Comment: This is useful only if a single element is nested.

Comment: @AshRj:  Now handles multi-element lists with some sanity.

Comment: I am assuming the first test is to check for empty lists ? But there already is a check len(a)==1 which will handle empty lists ..

Comment: The len(a)==1 should be before the isinstance check for it to handle empty lists

Answer (score 0):

recursive solution:

```
def strip(a):
    if len(a)==1:
        if isinstance(a[0], list):
            a=a[0]
            return strip(a)
        else:
            return a
    return a
```

Comment: @AshRj, what would be the expected output in that case though?

Comment: Depending on state of the program, you could want to return either the first list or the second list.

Comment: `strip([['a']]) -> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: true about the single element lists, I added an instance check

Comment: @COpython The OP hasnt **specified** that there will only be one element :) But ,anyways, point taken.

Comment: Also note the OP has a nested list of strings, not numbers (and that matters).